# Invalid scope for Youtube API CommentThreads - java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I'm new to Youtube data API and I'm trying to develop a standalone java application on my computer to parse some comments form Youtube videos. The sample code for CommentThreads-list is provided on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

```
// Sample Java code for user authorization

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeScopes;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ApiExample {

/** Application name. */
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "API Sample";

/** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/java-youtube-api-tests");

/** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 *
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
 */
private static final Collection<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader( in ));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
    flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
        "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized API client service, such as a YouTube
 * Data API client service.
 * @return an authorized API client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static YouTube getYouTubeService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new YouTube.Builder(
    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();

    try {
        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("part", "snippet,replies");
        parameters.put("videoId", "m4Jtj2lCMAA");

        YouTube.CommentThreads.List commentThreadsListByVideoIdRequest = youtube.commentThreads().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
        if (parameters.containsKey("videoId") && parameters.get("videoId") != "") {
            commentThreadsListByVideoIdRequest.setVideoId(parameters.get("videoId").toString());
        }

        CommentThreadListResponse response = commentThreadsListByVideoIdRequest.execute();
        System.out.println(response);


    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : " + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

[After I run the above sample code in eclipse, the browser opens but it shows "Error: invalid_scope". I've attached an image to show this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpRxp.png)

As for my OAuth client ID, I created a credential on youtube developer console and I selected "Other" as an Application Type for my project.

I also tried "Web application" and I assigned my localhost http://localhost/Callback for the Authorized redirect URIs. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should specify the correct scopes in your code, check these changes please.

```
private static final Collection<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");
```

Also, I think it would be good to know existing ones to detect which you need more. All youtube scopes begins: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/` (this part will be missed/skipped in scope examples to reduce duplication)

### YouTube Analytics API v1:

```
auth/youtube
youtube.readonly
youtubepartner
yt-analytics-monetary.readonly
yt-analytics.readonly
```

### YouTube Data API v3:

```
youtube
youtube.force-ssl
youtube.readonly
youtube.upload
youtubepartner
youtubepartner-channel-audit
```

### YouTube Reporting API v1

```
yt-analytics-monetary.readonly
yt-analytics.readonly
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Issue solved. All I needed was                   
private static final Collection<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

Comment: tour question has very helpful description. No need additional questions and so on.